# python version upgrade from 3.7 to 3.8 with the package phoenixdb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

i am trying to added the layer in lambda function i am using phoenixdb and i am getting error like this

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'gssapi.raw.creds'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

```
import phoenixdb
```

.....

Script is working fine in version 3.7 and I need to update in 3.8 with the package `phoenixdb`.

I tried with only `phoenixdb` folder zip and added in layer same error.

Need to resolve this, and get any other way to resolve this guide me to resolve it.

Comment: Simply reinstall the required packages with pip 3.8 (`python3.8 -m pip install phoenixdb` is probably safest if you're using multiple Python versions next to each other).

Comment: i tried this method also but no use and i created a seperate env also for package installation but end result is same error i am getting

Comment: And did you install the gssapi?

Comment: yes it is added when i am trying to install.